# Tkinter: Show./Hide Specific Text in a Textbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

DESCRIPTION:

I have a textbox with text in it. See the image below.

[image]

---

QUESTION:

I want the highlighted text to hide when I click the "Hide" button. And then show the text, when I click the Show button (not there in the picture).
Similar to pack() and pack_forget(), but this time, for text and not widget.

Comment: If you hide some text, do you want it to come back in the same place? What if someone writes something where it was?

Comment: @qr7NmUTjF6vbA4n8V3J9: Yes. At the same place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a tag to a region of text, and configure the tag with `elide=True` to hide the text, and set it to `elide=False` to show it.

Here's a little example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def hide():
    text.tag_add("hidden", "sel.first", "sel.last")

def show_all():
    text.tag_remove("hidden", "1.0", "end")

root = tk.Tk()
toolbar = tk.Frame(root)
hide_button = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Hide selected text", command=hide)
show_button = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Show all", command=show_all)
hide_button.pack(side="left")
show_button.pack(side="left")

text = tk.Text(root)
text.tag_configure("hidden", elide=True, background="red")

with open(__file__, "r") as f:
    text.insert("end", f.read())

toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

text.tag_add("sel", "3.0", "8.0")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @Bryan , how to use  the option text.delete().

Comment: @Mathan: that can be answered by reading the documentation for the text widget, and has nothing to do with this question and answer.